# java: identify the actual http connection

Tags: java, http, httpserver, httpsession, com.sun.net.httpserver

I'm developing a HTTP server using HttpServer class. The code is like the following.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8989), 0);
    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor

    server.start();
  }

  static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
         /*
             Some code here
         */
    }
  }
```

What I want is to find something (an id variable or an object) that identifyies the actual connection in the handler function.

If I make a break-point in the handler, I debug the server, then I run a client, I can see the content of httpExchange:

[image]

I think that connection attribute is a good choice. But I can't find how to get it from httpExchange, or its id.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Don't try to hurry anyone here. Have you tried [`HttpExchange#getAttribute(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: yes I tried with this: httpExchange.getAttribute("connection") it gives null.

Comment: Where are you setting this attribute?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Usually your are interested in the session, not the connection.

Comment: @EJP yes but I didn't find how to get the session, but when debugging I found that httpExchange contains the httpconnection so I said may be I can exploit it to achieve what I want

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I didn't set it. it's just an attempt. the attribute that I'm looking for is set automatically